# Using ajax fileupload and codeignitert to save blob on server

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, file-upload, blob

So in my project the user can record himself and then I get a blob file from a recorderplugin I'm using. I'm trying to upload that blob to the server via a fileupload  ajax call in codeigniter but I cannot find out how to get it working.

This is my javascript code: (

```
recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
     console.log(blob);
        $.ajaxFileUpload({
                url :  "../ajax/saverecording/", 
                secureuri      :false,
                fileElementId  :"geenidee",
                dataType : blob.type,
                data: blob.data,
                success: function(data, status) {
                    if(data.status != 'error')
                        alert("hoera!");
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            });
        });
```

This is my saverecording function in the ajax.php controller

```
public function saverecording()
{
    $status = "";
    $msg = "";
    $file_element_name = 'komaan';
    if ($status != "error")
    {
          $config['upload_path'] = '../../upload/audio/recordings/';
          $config['allowed_types'] = 'wav';
          $this->load->library('upload', $config);
          if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name))
          {
             $status = 'error';
             $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
             echo 'alert("this is not working!");';
          }
          else
          {
             $data = $this->upload->data();
          }
          @unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
       }
}
```

$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name) is returning false but why I don't know. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Btw I followed this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the file input but you can upload it with ajax:

```
recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
    $.ajax( "something.php", {
        data: blob,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        method: "POST",
        success: function() {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this gave me a new push in the right direction (I think) but I'm stuck again. I changed my question to where I'm now.